# Why we are not installed the Apache 2.4.58 version using apt-get for ubuntu 22.04 LTS version?

Tags: apt

When we install, apt-get is installed with the default version. The default version contains certain vulnerabilities. As a result, we did not install the newest version of Apache using the apt-get command.

Comment: Are you sure that version contains the vulnerabilities or was the older version patched for security fixes as it usually is for Ubuntu? Did you verify that your current version isn't patched by checking the [Ubuntu Security Notices](https://ubuntu.com/security/notices?order=newest&release=jammy&details=apache)? If you're talking about CVE-2023-45802, CVE-2023-31122, or CVE-2023-43622, then the version you're currently running, 2.4.52-1ubuntu4.7, has already been patched.